# HP 5800 interface card/module installation

Tags: hp, line-card

Is it possible to install an interface card, in this case LSW1GP16P0 to a HP 5800(JC103A) without powering off the switch? The installation guide is not very clear on that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interface cards on the 5800 series are all hot swappable.

The *HPE 5820X & 5800 Switch Series Installation Guide* has them listed as "Hot swappable interface cards" on p. 87.

Comment: It seems I was looking at an outdated guide. Thank you!